# How to find untranslated strings? (android)

Tags: android, resources

I have an application that should support several different languages.
And sometimes I forget to put translations for one of languages.

Is there any why to find strings which don't have a translation in one of strings.xml (locale specific) files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Get missing translations for strings-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985366/android-get-missing-translations-for-strings-resources)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ADT 16 will incorporate Android Lint tool - http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

It will check consistency of translation strings as well as other potential code issues.

This issue has also been raised in the past: [Android: Get missing translations for strings-resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985366/android-get-missing-translations-for-strings-resources)