# Android Lint Doesn't Show Translation Missing Errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint

I am using Android SDK 16.1 with Eclipse on Windows.

I've set ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS as a Windows environment variable per [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks)

I've rebooted my computer.

I've verified the System.getenv("ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS") uses Windows System Variables.

I've verified that translation errors are turned on.

However, what I'm wanting/expecting to error is not.  I have an English string in "/res/values/strings.xml" that is not in "/res/values-xx/strings.xml".  I expect lint to error because I've set ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS.  Looking at the source in the SDK, it seems like it should work.

Anyone got something else I should try?

Update:
I have tried this on a Mac and while I have persisted ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS="1", I can't get an error to occur in Eclipse.

Comment: Same problem for me on MacOSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever this problem was, upgrading to Android SDK 17 fixes this issue for me. Lint can now detect when I do not translate a string.

Answer (score 0):

I set it as a user variable (Windows XP), verified that it appears in a cmd prompt with the set command, and it appears to be working in eclipse after restarting it.

Comment: Can you try the scenario of putting a string in the default strings.xml only? Does it warn/error if the string only exists in the default?

Comment: Yes - that is the whole point of the MissingTranslations feature.
You use ANDROID_LINT_COMPLETE_REGIONS if you have a language (ex. fr) and a region where you want full set of strings for (fr-rCA).

I would also strongly recommend the tool from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985366/android-get-missing-translations-for-strings-resources