# How do you manage translations for your Android app?

Tags: android, internationalization, translation

Lint tool tells you about hardcoded strings or missing translations, but how about if you want to update an existing string?

How do you keep track of which strings need to be translated again when you update an existing string?

One solution is to use a new key in strings.xml if you want to change a string, however this requires updating all references in code that used the old key.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have all your string already externalized to a strings.xml file, translating and placing it in the correct folder should be easy enough.

Comment: The question is how to manage existing translations as you update your app. How to  keep track of which strings were updated between different app versions and therefore need new translations.

Comment: Look at the VCS logs before releasing?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? None of these answers address your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have translation for a language Android OS will choose your default values that are stored in the value folder.

To work with localisations you can also use  `Sequoyah Android Localization Editor`. Using it you can see all the string keys and assigned values. Here is a snapshot of it:
[image: Android Localization Editor]

So for each localization you will have a separate column.

Comment: To follow up on @Yury, the Sequoyah project is here: http://eclipse.org/sequoyah/. Just install the plugins into your own Eclipse. We use this project in the MOTODEV tools.  Installation guide here: http://eclipse.org/sequoyah/downloads/index.php#update_site.  The difference between these plugins and the plugins for MOTODEV is the availability of the automated translation piece, which for legal reasons we could not open-source.

Comment: The only downside of this answer is that Sequoyah development has stalled, and will probably be closed: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah/Termination_Review

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use your version control software to retrieve the list of strings that have changed since the previous version of your project.

Answer (score 0):

> > One solution is to use a new key in strings.xml if you want to change a string, however this requires updating all references in code that used the old key.

What would solve that? If you add a new string, you still have to add it to all `strings.xml` files.

What's the problem with updating the string on each `string.xml` file?

Comment: When a string is updated, all translations need to be updated as well, however I'm not the one who is translating the app, so I need a way of keeping track of which strings were updated between different versions and require new translations.

Comment: I am currently writing an application to assist with this exact problem. It is about 60% done. Send a mail to the address in my bio if you would like to see\test it when done.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `MOTODEV Studio's Localization tool`

video tutorial [here](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/motodevstudio/video/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference to our tools.  One thing to point out now (sadly) is the Google Translate APIs now cost money to use, so the machine translation feature isn't as nice as it was.  If you want to continue to use it, you have to provide your own API key in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I created this Java tool for automatic conversion of Android XML strings to CSV and back from CSV to XML. You can share the CSV file with your translators e.g. in Google Docs and when the changes are done you can convert it back to XML.

A solution to your particular problem could be as follows: open the CSV file in a spreadsheet application. If you edit a translation in a particular language, you can mark other language's translations (e.g. by different colour). In that case, the translators will know it was updated. After they also update the translation, they can remove the mark.

The tool can be downloaded here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60605726/AndroidXmlStringsConversionTool.jar

The arguments are:

```
<xmlToCsv|csvToXml> <path-to-android-project> <csv-file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [android2po](https://github.com/miracle2k/android2po) to automatically convert to po files and then import the translations.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android Studio/IntelliJ plugin that I created to convert all the strings.xml in different values-* folders into a single csv so I can upload them to Google Drive for my translators to work on it.

After they are done with the translation work I just convert them back to csv and let the plugin to convert the csv back to their respective values-*/string.xml.

You can download **Android Strings.xml to CSV Converter** in the Jetbrain plugin repositories from Android Studio/IntelliJ.