# Android Localization tool

Tags: android, localization

I have text resources in android, some are already translated whereas others are missing.

Is there a tool that can import e.g. the values xml file in addition to values xml file for Italian and checks what is missing and helps inserting the missing translations?

I tried OmegaT. This program imports the android resource and also writes into it. However, it did not show already translated stuff. Virtaal Translator does not support the xml files as input.

I would like to have a simple tool outside Eclipse, so that I may provide this tools to others helping to translate things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you manage translations for your Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113707/how-do-you-manage-translations-for-your-android-app)

Answer (score 5):

I found [POEditor.com](http://POEditor.com) to be the best and easiest to use for Android strings translation.
It supports Android XML strings import and I believe you can import your different files into the same translation and this will fill up your missing definitions.
The export will give you an XML with all your definitions together.
Oh, and it has also auto-translation or you can invite translators/friends to work with you only by inserting their email in that translation.

Answer (score 4):

[Weblate](http://weblate.org/en/) is a an open source web-based tool by Michal Čihař which also supports Android and has a very tight Git integration.

I've been using this tool to translate several project and I also used it to translate Weblate itself, I've seen better in terms of translator friendliness but the overall experience was very good.

Answer (score 3):

There is a project called Sequoyah. This is a special plugin for Eclipse. It does not allow you to translate automatically but you can easily see where and which translation values are missed. I've described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113707/how-do-you-manage-translations-for-your-android-app/9113883#9113883).

Comment: Unfortunately Sequoyah is being discontinued, so it might not be an option for the future: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah/Termination_Review

Answer (score 1):

I just started writing this tool: https://github.com/BenoitDuffez/OAT/wiki/Gallery

It is aimed to be self-hosted, free; it supports CDATA, `formatted="false"`, multiple xml files, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Agama App Translator tool](http://www.agamasoftware.com/agama_app_translator.php).
This is complete localization tool for Android with built-in google translator. It supports XML strings as well as menu XML files. You can easily add new language and let fill untranslated items with default (original) text or translate items as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Lokalise](http://lokalise.co). There is a free plan, and you could upload almost any format from different platforms.

I've been using it myself, and there is virtually no other tool better for managing translations.

Comment: can you tell me does lokalise slow down your app start time ? how does the synching work ? is it real time ?

Comment: @j2emanue as far as I can tell, the load time is not changed. Syncing is going on in the background, and new translation are used only when they are ready (can require an app restart after new translations are downloaded).