# Language strings view in ADT

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an android application with multiple langugae string files located like this:

res:
 -> values -> strings.xml
 -> values-da -> strings.xml

I used to be able to get a special view where I could see and edit both files in the same window/grid. A bit like an Excel sheet - but now I just can't get it to Work.

All I see is one of the following two screens which I don't want to use. do you have an answer to this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you should install a special plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113707/how-do-you-manage-translations-for-your-android-app/9113883#9113883

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed. If you make it to an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: I've added the answer )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To perform the actions you've described you need to install `Sequoyah` plugin. It has `Sequoyah Android Localization Editor` tool that shows all string keys and respective values in different languages in one table. The information about Sequoyah project is located here: http://eclipse.org/sequoyah Installation guide is here: http://eclipse.org/sequoyah/downloads/index.php#update_site.