# Is there a way how to edit multiple localised string.xml files in one window in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, localization

When working on a localized Android application, I found it a bit annoying that whenever I change a value in one language version of the `strings.xml`, I have to remember to change it also in the other versions.

Is there any way how to open multiple (or at least two of them) `string.xml` files in one window that would display the language versions of all the messages side by side, in a similar way to a resource bundle editor?

Comment: You might also consider MOTODEV Studio for Android, which (IIRC) has a grid showing strings and languages, for easier editing.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thank you for this tip. If you put this comment of yours into an answer, I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: Yeah, well, if the product site had a link showing that the feature was still there, I would provide an answer and link to it. Since I cannot determine for certain if the feature is still there, this is best left as a comment. The feature existed ~9 months ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7015450/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare, it's still there on http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/features/. Maybe I need to reword the text to be less about the automated translation ability now that Google Translate is a paid API.  Thx for the mention.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a followup to the others, yes there is a multi-language strings.xml editor in MOTODEV Studio.

Install as a set of plugins into Eclipse by visiting the Eclipse Marketplace (Help->Eclipse Marketplace) or by creating a new update site (Help->Install New Software) and using https://studio-android.motodevupdate.com/android/4.0/basic as the update site address.

If it doesn't open automatically the first time, right click on strings.xml and choose "Open With->Other" and find "Localization Files Editor". After that it should open this editor every time.

[image]

Here's a YouTube video showing how it works: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Asv-IoH9M0

Disclaimer: I'm the Product Manager for MOTODEV Studio.

Comment: What happened to Motodev Studio?  I really want that localization file editor back.

Comment: I'm afraid MOTODEV Studio was discontinued. The MOTODEV site was shut down and all the people who ran the site and created the tools were either reassigned or laid off in August. It worked with the R20 tools, but we couldn't test with the tools that just came out with 4.2. All the code for MOTODEV Studio that wasn't from Eclipse is now checked into AOSP under ./tools/motodev so presumably Google (or the community) can do something with it if they wish. Good luck, thanks for all the fish.

Comment: Android Localization Files Editor is now part of Eclipse Tools (was Sequoyah):

http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/

Comment: An update on the MOTODEV plugins saga.  After sitting in the AOSP for a while, an individual has stepped up to maintain the build and integration.  David Carver (@kingargyle) deserves the credit for this. He has an update site on github that I've tested and does work. It brings the old MOTODEV localization strings editor back and working with Eclipse Kepler.  https://github.com/kingargyle

Answer (score 3):

Yes, i too faced this issue in one project that was requiring multiple language support and i don't think so that there is any such tool to do this. But we can tile the window in eclipse and do the editing for two languages parallely[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use the following eclipse update site: http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.1/

Make sure you uncheck 'Group items by category' or you will not see any available packages!

Select the 'Sequoyah android Localization Editor' and install the package.

Right click on one of your 'strings.xml' file and select open with -> other -> 'Localization Files Editor'

Comment: This editor seemed fine at first, but behaves a little buggy (at least in my Eclipse Keppler) - doesn't handle multiline values very well and also automatically escapes HTML tags (which I use for formatted textviews).

Answer (score 1):

You can install MOTODEV Studio for Android. It has bunch of things including Android Localization Files Editor.
http://developer.motorola.com/tools/motodevstudio/features/

Answer (score 1):

Very old question but with a new answer. In Android Studio use the language editor for a side by side language editor.

[image]

See https://developer.android.com/studio/write/translations-editor.html